# SQL Query - Multiple columns into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've had a hunt round here and google and been un able to find anything.

I did come accross the CONCAT function, but as my company runs SQL Server 2008 thats not an option :(

I have a query that outputs multiple columns / rows and I want to disply the results all in one column.

Example:

```
SELECT client, owner, payer, status
FROM Main
WHERE status = 'Active'
```

Result:

```
client | owner | payer | status

1      |  2    |  3    | Active
10     |  11   | 12    | Active
```

What I Want it to look like

```
ColumnX  |
1
2
3 
Active
10
11
12
Active
```

Thanks in advance for your help and I hope that makes sense :)

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: This is a bad idea. Without a key you will have no idea what these values mean. You will have no sort order.

Comment: I'm curious about what you're trying to do with this query.  Perhaps there's a better way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: thanks thanks for the quick reply.  just trying to get a list of numbers that are 'active' it doesn't matter where they come from. will try the below when I'm back.at my desk!

Comment: As below, UNIONALL Method worked a charm! Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are referring to is known as an [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). This takes the columns and converts them to rows:

```
SELECT value, field
FROM
(
  select cast(client as varchar(10)) client, 
    cast(owner as varchar(10)) owner, 
    cast(payer as varchar(10)) payer, 
    status
  from main
  where status = 'Active'
) x
unpivot
(
  value 
  for field in (client, owner, payer, status)
) u
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de73b)

The `UNPIVOT` will give you the list of values in one column and then the column it came from in the other.

The thing that is required with an `UNPIVOT` is that all fields be of the same datatype, so you will need to perform a conversion of the datatypes so they can be presented in the same column.

You could also use a `UNION ALL` to perform this operation but again you will need to `cast()` the datatypes to be the same:

```
SELECT cast(client as varchar(10)) value
FROM main
WHERE status = 'active'
UNION ALL
SELECT cast(owner as varchar(10)) value
FROM main
WHERE status = 'active'
UNION All
SELECT cast(payer as varchar(10)) value
FROM main
WHERE status = 'active'
UNION ALL
SELECT status
FROM main
WHERE status = 'active'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de73b/3)

Comment: Sure, but you rolled it back. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think cause I was editing it when you were too.  Reason why we need to lock posts while editing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at SQL Pivot? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

To my knowledge, you would need to UnPivot your table, which would produce a massive stack.